# How to achieve an dashed EditText in Android where color of dash changes as input is taken

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to achieve the following:

[image]

Here, with every input the color of dash changes and the number of dashes is also equal to the `maxLength` of the `EditText`.

How do I achieve this in Android?

Comment: You know I checked this thing with Google's Duo app and there they had separate widgets for each entry. I think thats the way to go. You can check that for the app above by enabling showing of layout bounds from the Developer options.

Comment: If you are seeing this in an example application, there are helpful developer tools to give hints toward how the implementation was done. Here I would turn on "show layout bounds" in the developer options under your device's settings. This would reveal the view is most likely separate widgets for each numeral.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [material-code-input](https://github.com/glomadrian/material-code-input) library to achieve a dashed EditText.